# How can I create 'pages' from scratch to be printed or print previewed in c#?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, system.drawing, system.printing

Due to the overwhelming complexity and/or limited license capabilities of the components available for this job, I have decided to write this component from scratch. This is something I have fully functional in PHP, and in VB6. but I am hitting a wall when trying to add a `page` .

A lot of great examples on how to print from file, or how to print a single page (all graphics etc are hard coded for the pages inside the Print event), but nothing on how to setup a collection to hold the page data, and then send those to be printed.

In vb6, you can obtain the pagebounds and call new page, but in .NET, there doesn't seem to be a new page method.

Following is the source I have so far, which is pretty rough due to the apparent lack of this basic functionality.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

using PdfFileWriter;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.ComponentModel;

using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

class PDF : PrintDocument {
    /// <summary>
    /// Logo to display on invoice
    /// </summary>
    public Image Logo { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pages drawn in document
    /// </summary>
    private List<Graphics> Pages;

    private int CurrentPage;

    private string directory;
    private string file;

    /// <summary>
    /// Current X position
    /// </summary>
    public int X { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Current X position
    /// </summary>
    public int Y { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the folder where backups, downloads, etc will be stored or retrieved from
    /// </summary>
    [Editor( typeof( System.Windows.Forms.Design.FolderNameEditor ), typeof( System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor ) )]
    public string Folder { get { return directory; } set { directory=value; } }

    public PDF() {
        file = (string)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds.ToString();
        directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

        CurrentPage = 0;

        // initialize pages array
        Pages = new List<Graphics>();

        PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings() {
            PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF",
            PrintToFile = true,
            PrintFileName = Path.Combine(directory, file + ".pdf"),
        };

        DefaultPageSettings = new PageSettings(PrinterSettings) {
            PaperSize=new PaperSize("Letter", 850, 1100 ),
            Landscape = false,
            Margins = new Margins(left: 50, right: 50, top: 50, bottom: 50),
        };
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Get specific page
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="page">page number. 1 based array</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Graphics GetPage( int page ) {
        int p = page - 1;
        if ( p<0||p>Pages.Count ) { return null; }
        return Pages[p];
    }

    public Graphics GetCurrentPage() {
        return GetPage(CurrentPage);
    }

    protected override void OnBeginPrint( PrintEventArgs e ) {
        base.OnBeginPrint( e );
    }

    protected override void OnPrintPage( PrintPageEventArgs e ) {
        base.OnPrintPage( e );
    }

    protected override void OnEndPrint( PrintEventArgs e ) {
        base.OnEndPrint( e );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new page to the document
    /// </summary>
    public void NewPage() {
        // Add a new page to the page collection and set it as the current page
        Graphics g = Graphics.CreateCraphics(); // not sure if this works, but no CreateGraphics is available
        Pages.Add( g );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new string to the current page
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The string to print</param>
    /// <param name="align">Optional alignment of the string</param>
    public void DrawString(string text, System.Windows.TextAlignment align = System.Windows.TextAlignment.Left ) {
        // add string to document
        Pages[CurrentPage].DrawString(text, new Font("Arial", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(X, Y));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Save the contents to PDF
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="FileName"></param>
    public void Save( string FileName ) {
        // Start the print job looping through pages.
        foreach ( Graphics page in Pages ) {
            // there doesn't seem to be an addpage method
        }

        /*
         *  From stackoverflow article on how to 'print' a pdf to filename as the poster complained
         *  that the PrinterSettings.PrintFileName property is ignored. Havn't tested yet. Also, no
         *  such function as 'PrintOut' so further research required.
         * 
                PrintOut(
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    FileName,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value
                );
        */
    }

}
```

I am not looking for a really long winded massive project on how to write PDF documents as they are all very restrictive, each of them has at least one limitation which is a problem for the layout I intend to design (upgrade from PHP which was an upgrade from VB6). The end result layout looks like this >

## First Page (Invoice main page )

[image: Invoice First Page]

## Second Page(s) [summary]

This report may have more pages depending on how many items are in payments and services. Header of the sub-report that continues rolls over to the next page if there are many items. For example, if a customer has 200 services, those items will continue in a similar fashion using the same "Payments" header block at the start of each consecutive page.

[image: Invoice Second Page]

## Detailed Reports

There may be multiple detail reports, each one starting at the beginning of a new page, and the page counter is reset and printed for those pages. So page 6 of the invoice might actually be Page 3 of the second detail report. Each report starts and ends like the following (and picture depicts layout of field data, etc)

### Report first page

[image: Report First Page]

### Report last page

[image: Report Last Page]

## What am I looking for ?

A reliable way to make the above multi-report invoice layout work in Visual Studio .NET.  I am looking to port code away from php and vb6, and I am not interested in using libraries that are either massive in distribution size, or ridiculously complex / limited license restrictions. Microsoft provides some very powerful tools built-in, and I am not adverse to using the built-in PDF print driver and spooling the data, even though that is a bit of a hack, it does seem to be the least complex method to make this functional without the restrictions or bloat of 3rd party controls. (including open source, as the ones I looked at tend to do some very strange conversions to char, then maybe latex or something, not entirely sure what all the conversion stuff is about).

## NOTE

It is very important to understand that the combination of the above report styles make up ONE invoice, and thus only one pdf file per client. If it helps, here is a VB6 backwards compatability method exposing the traditional 'Print' object [printing compatability vb6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.compatibility.vb6.printer.newpage.aspx). This should help clarify the native functionality I am looking to create/use.

[image: VB6]

I am having a difficult time swallowing the above "no direct equivalent" statement, as adding a new page when creating a document in memory seems to be a pretty basic (and essential) function of creating a document for print. It doesn't make sense that everything needed to be printed MUST be loaded from a file first.

Comment: Rather than creating a PDF directly we solved a similar issue by creating the document in html, then using [TuesPechkin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TuesPechkin) to convert the html to a PDF. It took some work to get page boundaries to play nicely, but it works very well

Comment: @Paddy - seems that control is built requiring http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html , so why not just use the command line tool they offer ?  not sure what the advantage would be.  Just to clarify; I have looked into converting from html to pdf as a workaround for the above issue, The library does seem a bit ovecomplicated however some things they did (eg, page type actually working directly) is nice.  I am just having a difficult time chewing that this hasn't been done in c#/.net, as even VB6 can manage this trivial task easily.

Comment: `using PdfFileWriter;` line is quite misleading, since the library is then not used in the code...

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal - i have tried that one, and if I print a table, I can't add any other data to that page.

Comment: So your question is about that library or about printing without that library?

Comment: @SanuelJackson As you said, TuesPechkin gave us the ability to use it directly in C#, rather than deal with VC++ libraries and command line utilities.

Comment: Did you check this one? http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/733680/Printing-and-Previewing-multiple-pages-in-Csharp

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal - the question is how to do this natively.  aka, where is the `.NewPage()` functionality, and how can I draw to that, then send the pages created to the printer (in this case i selected Microsoft Print to PDF.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal - if you look at the example, it is doing what I don't want to do. I do not want to write a massive `OnPrint` that is custom. I need to design the pages, and *then* print.

Comment: @Paddy - true. I suppose I could always write a COM object in VB6, and include that in my .NET project as well. Kind of silly though as .NET seems capable, just missing (or i am unable to locate) how to make new pages, and then print them after making them -- not lump everything inside the print page event. I don't feel it is unreasonable to expect this capability exists somewhere inside .net.  :)

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal : This link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.compatibility.vb6.printer.newpage.aspx  (also added to post) should demonstrate more clearly what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I have an idea that might work.  If I can somehow create a new Graphics object with the dimensions, and margins set as a Printer Graphics object, then I could hack something together by exposing those draw methods, and then loop through them inside the on print method.  Any ideas on how this may be done ?

Comment: Are you aware that you are moving from ancient VB6 to already very obsolete Windows.Forms? There are more ways of printing than just `System.Drawing.Printing` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my implementation of a working solution to this problem, allowing a user to completely design the document in a reusable manner without ever requiring to send the `.Print` command.

The concept of using an Image to store the data was in part due to a comment by [Bradley Uffner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526724/bradley-uffner) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431875/is-there-a-way-to-combine-two-system-drawing-graphics-objects-together) regarding combining two `Graphics` objects

There are several advantages and disadvantages to handling the process in this manner broken down below.

**Advantages**

- The printer stuff is more modular, and reusable in other projects with different print requirements
- Pages can be removed or even inserted (depending on the type of reports being done, this could save a lot of database query time where a cover page requires a summary, but the details for that summary are to be printed later)
- Pages can be saved individually as image files
- Pages can be serialized
- The `OnPrintPage` isn't overly complex
- Dynamic page positioning on current page or any other page in the array. Very easy to switch and place data elsewhere.

**Disadvantages**

- Uses a bit more resources. Potential memory limitations if the Image array gets really big.

## Class File

This also demonstrates how portable this is, as anyone can reuse it quickly. I am still working on wrapping the Draw methods, however this code demonstrates the objective needing only to really extend with more draw methods, and possibly some other features I may have missed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.ComponentModel;

using System.IO;

class PDF : PrintDocument {
    /// <summary>
    /// Logo to display on invoice
    /// </summary>
    public Image Logo { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Current X position on canvas
    /// </summary>
    public int X { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Current Y position on canvas
    /// </summary>
    public int Y { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the folder where backups, downloads, etc will be stored or retrieved from
    /// </summary>
    [Editor( typeof( System.Windows.Forms.Design.FolderNameEditor ), typeof( System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor ) )]
    public string Folder { get { return directory; } set { directory=value; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Current font used to print
    /// </summary>
    public Font Font { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Current font color
    /// </summary>
    public Color ForeColor { get; set; }

    private int CurrentPagePrinting { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set printer margins
    /// </summary>
    public Margins PrintMargins {
        get { return DefaultPageSettings.Margins; }
        set { DefaultPageSettings.Margins = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Pages drawn in document
    /// </summary>
    public List<Image> Pages { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The current selected page number. 0 if nothing selected
    /// </summary>
    private int CurrentPage;

    /// <summary>
    /// The current working directory to save files to
    /// </summary>
    private string directory;

    /// <summary>
    /// The currently chosen filename
    /// </summary>
    private string file;

    /// <summary>
    /// Public acceisble object to all paperSizes as set
    /// </summary>
    public List<PrintPaperSize> PaperSizes { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Object for holding papersizes
    /// </summary>
    public class PrintPaperSize {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Height { get; set; }
        public double Width { get; set; }

        public PaperKind Kind { get; set; }

        public PrintPaperSize() {
            Height = 0;
            Width = 0;
            Name = "";
            Kind = PaperKind.Letter;
        }

        public PrintPaperSize( string name, double height, double width, PaperKind kind ) {
            Height=height;
            Width=width;
            Name=name;
            Kind=kind;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Set the spacing between lines in percentage. Affects Y position. Range(%): 1 - 1000
    /// </summary>
    private int lineSpacing;
    public int LineSpacing {
        get {
            return lineSpacing;
        }
        set {
            if(value > 0 && value < 1000) {
                lineSpacing = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Current papersize selected. used for some calculations
    /// </summary>
    public PrintPaperSize CurrentPaperSize { get; private set; }

    public PDF() {
        // set the file name without extension to something safe
        file = (string)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds.ToString();

        // set the save directory to MyDocuments
        directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        CurrentPage = 0;

        // initialize pages array
        Pages = new List<Image>();

        // Set the initial font and color
        Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", (float)11.25, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        ForeColor = Color.Black;

        lineSpacing = 100;

        // set the printer to Microsoft's PDF printer and generate and ensure it will save to a file
        PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings() {
            PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF",
            PrintToFile = true,
            PrintFileName = Path.Combine(directory, file + ".pdf"),
        };

        // hide the notice 'printing' while spooling job.
        PrintController = new StandardPrintController();

        // set the printer quality to maximum so we can use this for getting the dpi at this setting
        DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.Kind = PrinterResolutionKind.High;

        // store all paper sizes at 1 dpi [ reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/05169a47-04d5-4890-9b0a-7ad11a6a87f2/need-pixel-width-for-paper-sizes-a4-a5-executive-letter-legal-executive?forum=csharpgeneral ]
        PaperSizes = new List<PrintPaperSize>();
        foreach ( PaperSize P in PrinterSettings.PaperSizes ) {
            double W=P.Width/100.0;
            double H=P.Height/100.0;
            PaperSizes.Add(
                new PrintPaperSize() {
                    Height = H,
                    Width = W,
                    Name = P.PaperName,
                    Kind = P.Kind
                }
            );

            if ( P.PaperName=="Letter" ) {
                CurrentPaperSize = PaperSizes[PaperSizes.Count-1];
            }
        }

        // setup the initial page type, orientation, margins, 
        using ( Graphics g=PrinterSettings.CreateMeasurementGraphics() ) {
            DefaultPageSettings = new PageSettings(PrinterSettings) {
                PaperSize=new PaperSize( CurrentPaperSize.Name, (Int32)(CurrentPaperSize.Width*g.DpiX), (Int32)(CurrentPaperSize.Height*g.DpiY) ),
                Landscape = false,
                Margins = new Margins(left: 100, right: 100, top: 10, bottom: 10),
                PrinterResolution=new PrinterResolution() {
                    Kind = PrinterResolutionKind.High
                }
            };
        }

        // constrain print within margins
        OriginAtMargins = false;
    }


    public void SetPaperSize( PaperKind paperSize ) {
        // TODO: Use Linq on paperSizes
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get specific page
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="page">page number. 1 based array</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Image GetPage( int page ) {
        int p = page - 1;
        if ( p<0||p>Pages.Count ) { return null; }
        return Pages[p];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the current page
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Image</returns>
     public Image GetCurrentPage() {
        return GetPage(CurrentPage);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Before printing starts
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">PrintEventArgs</param>
    protected override void OnBeginPrint( PrintEventArgs e ) {
         CurrentPagePrinting=0;
         base.OnBeginPrint( e );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Print page event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">PrintPageEventArgs</param>
    protected override void OnPrintPage( PrintPageEventArgs e ) {
        CurrentPagePrinting++;

        // if page count is max exit print routine
        if ( CurrentPagePrinting==Pages.Count ) { e.HasMorePages=false; } else { e.HasMorePages=true; }

        // ensure high resolution / clarity of image so text doesn't fuzz
        e.Graphics.CompositingMode=CompositingMode.SourceOver;
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality=CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

        // Draw image and respect margins (unscaled in addition to the above so text doesn't fuzz)
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(
            Pages[CurrentPagePrinting-1],
//          new Point(0,0)
            new Point(
                DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left,
                DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top
            )
        );
        base.OnPrintPage( e );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// After printing has been completed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">PrintEventArgs</param>
    protected override void OnEndPrint( PrintEventArgs e ) {
        base.OnEndPrint( e );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new page to the document
    /// </summary>
    public void NewPage() {
        // Add a new page to the page collection and set it as the current page

        Bitmap bmp;
        using(Graphics g = PrinterSettings.CreateMeasurementGraphics()) {
            int w=(Int32)( CurrentPaperSize.Width*g.DpiX )-(Int32)( ( ( DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left+DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right )/100 )*g.DpiX );
            int h=(Int32)( CurrentPaperSize.Height*g.DpiY )-(Int32)( ( ( DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top+DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom )/100 )*g.DpiY );
            bmp = new Bitmap( w, h );
            bmp.SetResolution(g.DpiX, g.DpiY);
        }

        // reset X and Y positions
        Y=0;
        X=0;

        // Add new page to the collection
        Pages.Add( bmp );
        CurrentPage++;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Change the current page to specified page number
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="page">page number</param>
    /// <returns>true if page change was successful</returns>
    public bool SetCurrentPage( int page ) {
        if ( page<1 ) { return false; }
        if ( page>Pages.Count ) { return false; }
        CurrentPage = page - 1;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove the specified page #
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="page">page number</param>
    /// <returns>true if successful</returns>
    public bool RemovePage(int page) {
        if ( page<1 ) { return false; }
        if ( page>Pages.Count ) { return false; }
        if ( Pages.Count-page==0 ) {
            CurrentPage = 0;
            Pages.RemoveAt(page - 1);
        } else {
            if ( page==CurrentPage && CurrentPage == 1 ) {
                Pages.RemoveAt(page - 1);
            } else {
                CurrentPage = CurrentPage - 1;
                Pages.RemoveAt(page -1);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new string to the current page
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The string to print</param>
    /// <param name="align">Optional alignment of the string</param>
    public void DrawString(string text, System.Windows.TextAlignment align = System.Windows.TextAlignment.Left ) {
        // add string to document
        using ( Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage( Pages[CurrentPage - 1] ) ) {
            g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

            // get linespacing and adjust by user specified linespacing
            int iLineSpacing=(Int32)( g.MeasureString( "X", Font ).Height*(float)( (float)LineSpacing/(float)100 ) );
            switch ( align ) {
                case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Left:
                case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Justify:
                    g.DrawString( text, Font, new SolidBrush( ForeColor ), new PointF( X, Y ) );
                    break;
                case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Right:
                    g.DrawString( text, Font, new SolidBrush( ForeColor ), new PointF( Pages[CurrentPage - 1].Width - g.MeasureString( text, Font ).Width, Y ) );
                    break;
                case System.Windows.TextAlignment.Center:
                    g.DrawString( text, Font, new SolidBrush( ForeColor ), new PointF( ( Pages[CurrentPage-1].Width+g.MeasureString( text, Font ).Width )/2, Y ) );
                    break;
            }
            Y+=iLineSpacing;
            if( Y + iLineSpacing > Pages[CurrentPage-1].Height ) {
                NewPage();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

## Example Usage

```
// initialize a new PrintDocument
PDF print = new PDF();

// set the font
print.Font = new Font("Helvetica", (float)12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);

// change the color (can be used for shapes, etc once their draw methods are added to the PDF() class)
print.ForeColor = Color.Red;

// create a new page !!!!
print.NewPage();

// add some text
print.DrawString( "Hello World !!" );

// add some right aligned text
print.DrawString( "Aligned Right", System.Windows.TextAlignment.Right );

// add some centered text
print.DrawString( "Aligned Right", System.Windows.TextAlignment.Center );

// change line spacing ( percentage between 1% and 1000% )
print.LineSpacing = 50; // 50% of drawstrings detected line height

// add another page
print.NewPage();

// print a couple lines
print.DrawString( "Hello World" );
print.DrawString( "Hello World" );

// change the color again and print another line
ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
print.DrawString( "Hello World" );

// duplicate a page (clone page 1 as page 3 )
print.NewPage();
print.Pages[print.Pages -1] = print.GetPage(1);

// go back to page 1 and print some more text at specified coordinates
print.SetCurrentPage(1);
print.X = 400;
print.Y = 300;
print.DrawString( "Drawn after 3rd page created" );

// send the print job
print.Print();

// reprint
print.Print();

// show a preview of the 2nd page
/*
    Image img = print.GetPage(1);
    pictureBox1.Height=(Int32)(print.CurrentPaperSize.Height*img.VerticalResolution);
    pictureBox1.Width = (Int32)(print.CurrentPaperSize.Width*img.HorizontalResolution);
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
    pictureBox1.Image = img;
*/
```

Comment: This class acts as a provider to allow full control over the document contents in memory BEFORE printing.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a very bare bones demo of the .NET printing system that mimics the basic invoice layout you specified.  Full code is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/BradleyUffner/dotnetinvoiceprintingdemo), but I will summarize the important parts below.  I'm going to continue working on this and improving it because it was kind of fun to create.

As of now, it produces output that looks like this:
[image]

Example of text quality:
[image]

`InvoiceDocument` is responsible for printing an instance of an `Invoice`:

```
class InvoiceDocument : PrintDocument
{
    public InvoiceDocument(Invoice invoice)
    {
        _invoice = invoice;
        _currentSection = new MainPage(this);
    }

    private Invoice _invoice;
    public Invoice Invoice => _invoice;

    private InvoiceSection _currentSection;
    public InvoiceSection CurrentSection => _currentSection;


    #region Fonts
    private Font _titleFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 18, FontStyle.Bold);
    public Font TitleFont => _titleFont;

    private Font _headerFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12, FontStyle.Regular);
    public Font HeaderFont => _headerFont;

    private Font _regularFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Regular);
    public Font RegularFont => _regularFont;

    private Font _boldFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold);
    public Font BoldFont => _boldFont;

    #endregion


    protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        _currentSection?.Render(e);
    }

    public void ChangeSection(InvoiceSection nextSection)
    {
        _currentSection = nextSection;
    }

}
```

`InvoiceDocument` is composed of subclasses of `InvoiceSection`.  Each section knows how to print different parts of the invoice, the main page, summary, details, etc. It is also responsible for knowing when and how to wrap to the next page:

```
abstract class InvoiceSection
{
    protected InvoiceSection(InvoiceDocument invoiceDocument)
    {
        this.InvoiceDocument = invoiceDocument;
    }

    public InvoiceDocument InvoiceDocument { get; }

    public abstract void Render(PrintPageEventArgs e);

    public Invoice Invoice => InvoiceDocument?.Invoice;
}


internal class MainPage : InvoiceSection
{

    public MainPage(InvoiceDocument invoiceDocument) : base(invoiceDocument) { }

    public override void Render(PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, e.MarginBounds.Left + 100, e.MarginBounds.Top + 100);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Invoice.CompanyName, InvoiceDocument.TitleFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top + 30);

        e.HasMorePages = true;
        InvoiceDocument.ChangeSection(new SummmarySection(InvoiceDocument));
    }
}


internal class SummmarySection : InvoiceSection
{
    public SummmarySection(InvoiceDocument invoiceDocument) : base(invoiceDocument)
    {
    }

    public override void Render(PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, e.MarginBounds.Left, e.MarginBounds.Top, e.MarginBounds.Width, 20);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Payments", InvoiceDocument.HeaderFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + 200, e.MarginBounds.Top + 2);

        int y = e.MarginBounds.Top + 25;

        while (_currentPaymentIndex < Invoice.Payments.Count && y < e.MarginBounds.Bottom)
        {
            Payment payment = Invoice.Payments[_currentPaymentIndex];

            e.Graphics.DrawString(payment.Description, InvoiceDocument.RegularFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + 150, y);
            e.Graphics.DrawString($"{payment.Amount:C}", InvoiceDocument.RegularFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Right - 150, y);

            y = y + InvoiceDocument.RegularFont.Height;

            _currentPaymentIndex++;
        }

        if (_currentPaymentIndex < Invoice.Payments.Count)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
        }
    }

    private int _currentPaymentIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Taking a look through this now.  I updated the other article with regards to graininess of using Image with it.  Inside the Render method you created, will it automatically make new pages if the index goes beyond the bounds ? from what it looks like, it will continue to draw off canvas, and not actually render it to print. (the code, not the demo  :)  )

Comment: It wraps to new pages automatically, I just edited the answer to add a (very zoomed out) screenshot.

Comment: I added a 100% zoom screenshot showing text quality.

Comment: The wrapping is specifically handled in the 2nd part of the `while` loop criteria, where it checks to see if `y > MarginBounds.Bottom`.  If it is, it stops iterating the loop, and sets `e.HasMorePages` to true.  The current position is stored in `_currentPaymentIndex` and is resumed from there on the next page render.

Comment: To complete this you would want to add an additional `DetailsSection` class and move to it the same way that `MainPage` moves to `SummarySection`.  I haven't gotten that far in my code yet.

Comment: You have used some interesting techniques so divide the code, but this still isn't very portable, or demonstrate how to make it accessible. The big problem is that the `PrintPageEventArgs` is not exposed until after calling `Print`.  I should be able to make calls to draw my elements without wrapping it inside `OnPrint`. You have done a good job, but all you have done here is pass the graphics object off to other methods. The code is still centralized and totally dependant on calling `Print` for any of it to execute.  Consider as something you would compile and reference

Comment: Having all the Draw / PrintString / etc methods entirely dependant of being coded inside of another element is a bit eh....  however, this does give me an idea which I may be able to whip up as a new Page type.

Comment: Reference from my question :  "nothing on how to setup a collection to hold the page data, and then send those to be printed".

Comment: Another concept, I could use reflection and a dummy graphics control which just appends the strings of the commands being sent, and then use a collection of strings, executing the code from strings when Print is called. in this way, the page layout can be created / designed and the methods can be exposed and thus accessible outside of the printer object.

Comment: Well, yes, all that is true.  That's why I was sure to note that it extremely rough, bare bones, and incomplete.  I only had 45 minutes to work on it.  It is in serious need of being beat with the refactoring hammer.

Comment: Managed to get the graphics method working. Apparently there was a Dpi mismatch between the bitmap, and the graphics print.  Also, DrawImageUnscaled() instead of DrawImage() which preserved the image quality.  This will have to work for now until I can figure out another way., but it does the job. I can now add/remove pages and shift between them dynamically without having to call print. NewPage() creates a new bitmap which acts as a canvas to draw on. Possible feature later to make each 'Draw' method it's own layer in an array within `Page`.

Comment: This is a great answer but is not using `System.Drawing.Printing` namespace from framework 1.1 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx now a bit obsolete? I mean there are perhaps better ways of printing in .NET now http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/printing-in-wpf/,  https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WPF-Printing-Overview-f28c541a#content

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal - I appreciate WPF, while some things are easier, it does make other things more complex.  I have posted a solution that meets the requisite objective and should clarify what it was I was looking to do (even though I thought it was clear I didn't want to inherit my code from the OnPrintPage event )